# How to limit cpu cores in mapreduce java code in hadoop

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm new in Hadoop and I want to limit allocated cpu cores in mapreduce jobs. But when I've used below configuration, I still see allocated cpu as 120 cores. How to limit allocated cpu cores in Hadoop?
I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707106/how-to-make-hadoop-use-all-the-cores-on-my-system) but it didn't work.

Here is my conf settings:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration ();
conf.set("mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores","40");
conf.set("mapreduce.reduce.cpu.vcores","40");
```

Hadoop version: 2.6.0

Comment: Is 120 total combined number of cores allotted to all the mappers? How many mappers do you have? Also, please check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174735/hadoop-adding-more-than-1-core-per-container-on-hadoop-2-7/33208258#33208258

Comment: Yes, total combined number of cores are 120 and i have 121 mapper. I can't change anything in xml files because there are lots of applications that they're in the same cluster and i want to change settings one of those applications.